# Java ArrayList equivalent for PHP

Tags: java, php

I'm preparing a strassen matrix algorithm using PHP. I've googled and found some similar projects in other languages like python, java ,...
Since in my opinion Java is most similar to PHP, I decided to turn the Java code to PHP. 
I turned the whole java code to PHP except the following part. I don't understand the meaning of `<` and `>>` symbols and what they do in this code.
Any Idea?

```
public static int[][] strassen(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> A,
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> B) {
    // Make the matrices bigger so that you can apply the strassen
    // algorithm recursively without having to deal with odd
    // matrix sizes
    int n = A.size();
    int m = nextPowerOfTwo(n);
    int[][] APrep = new int[m][m];
    int[][] BPrep = new int[m][m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            APrep[i][j] = A.get(i).get(j);
            BPrep[i][j] = B.get(i).get(j);
        }
    }

    int[][] CPrep = strassenR(APrep, BPrep);
    int[][] C = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            C[i][j] = CPrep[i][j];
        }
    }
    return C;
}
```

you can see the original code [here](http://martin-thoma.com/strassen-algorithm-in-python-java-cpp/)

Comment: it is nothing but Arraylist of Arraylists.

Comment: Do you mean ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Comment: `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` simply says that an ArrayList will hold an ArrayList that holds integers. PHP only supports type hints for arrays and object so I think you can use array as type hint in the method's signature. And keeps in mind that that code is nothing but a 2D array with kind of types hint in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

These are [ArrayList](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), and the closest PHP likeness to the `ArrayList` class from Java is the [ArrayObject](http://goo.gl/HPS9t3) class. The method names are different, but the functionality between the two is fairly close.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new in PHP too. May you turn this part to PHP for me?     strassen(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> A,
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> B)

Comment: We are here to help you not to do your job, I am Sorry.